# Measuring distance between two Lat/Lng points

Tags: sql

I am having issues trying to return the closest location to the user via an SQL statement. To test I am using the exact same coordinates, here is what I have:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  `companies`.`customerName` , 
    (3959 * 
        ACOS(
            COS(
                RADIANS(37.367485) * COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`gps_lat`)) * 
                COS(
                    RADIANS(`locations`.`gps_lng`) - RADIANS(-77.399994) + 
                    SIN(RADIANS(37.367485)) * SIN(RADIANS(`locations`.`gps_lat`))
                )
            )
        )
    )
AS  `distance` 
FROM  `locations` 
JOIN  `companies` ON  `locations`.`co_id` 
HAVING  `distance` > 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

**Results:**

```
| customerName  | distance           |
| SOME COMPANY  | 1914.41747964854   |
```

`locations` **table values:**

```
gps_lat   | gps_lng
37.367485 | -77.399994
```

I used the example from [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch#findnearsql), I checked the formula a couple times and I can't seem to come up with where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT:
Since there seems to be some confusion on me knowing what I am doing:

The `>` was substituted to yield a result, `1914` is obviously greater then `25`.

The application of this is passing user coordinates from an Android app to our web server. The Latitude and Longitude will be pulled from the `$_GET` values and cross-referenced from companies in our web servers MYSQL database.

**The syntax above is just me checking my SQL statement in Mysql Workbench. Obviously I am looking for a zero value result.**

Comment: If you want the closest, why to you restrict it to "distance > 25"?

Comment: I did, returned zero results. Note the distance it gave me above

Comment: Depending on what RDBMS you're using, there may be considerably simpler (and faster) ways to do this. Ex: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html), [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933876%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [PostgreSQL](http://postgis.refractions.net/).

Comment: The formula you are using is nothing like the ones on the Aviation Formulary http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Dist and also you have hard coded latitudes and longitudes that appear to be identical to the ones in the table, so you should be getting a distance of 0.

Comment: The use of this is passing user coordinates from an Android app to our web server. The Latitude and Longitude will be pulled from the `$_GET` values. The syntax above is just me checking my SQL statement in Mysql Workbench. I obviously am looking for a zero value result.

Comment: Just a note / warning....distance in meters (or any other type) requires a 4D object, not just the simple lat/lon 2d geometry.  A 4D object is lat/lon/altitude/curvature of the earth. A 1 degree change in lat/lon represents a much larger distance at the equator than at the north pole.  (sorry if you've already accounted for this in that formula...it's just easy to miss)

Comment: @Twelfth I appreciate your comment. The proximity of the locations to the users location shouldn't be significant enough to account for altitude but I did incorporate the curvature (in miles) of the earth using the `3959`, although this may not be significant enough to warrant inclusion either. But, I gathered that from the Google example and further research.

Comment: @ASOK that works...if you are in tiny distances, the earth can be called a 2d object for the most case.  I'm unsure of MySQL's support...but postgres offers POSTGIS support that has many of these functions already included.  You may want to consider using these functions instead of putting the logic together yourself.  For example, ST_Distance can be used to calc this in Postgres as: st_Distance(
   st_transform(st_geomfromtext('POINT('|| lon ||' ' ||lat ||')',4326),26929 ),
   st_transform(st_GeomFromText('POINT(-86.066069 33.566961 )',4326),26929)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have solved this issue by changing from Googles example to the formula provided by "Adventures of an adopted yooper". Using his/her version of the [Haversine Formula](http://sgowtham.net/blog/2009/08/08/mysql-finding-locations-nearest-to-a-given-pair-of-gps-coordinates/).
*Note: The Google example above is using Haversine as well.*

**SQL:**

```
SELECT  `companies`.`customerName` , 
(2 * (3959 * ATAN2(
          SQRT(
            POWER(SIN((RADIANS(37.367485 - `locations`.`gps_lat` ) ) / 2 ), 2 ) +
            COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`gps_lat`)) *
            COS(RADIANS(37.367485 )) *
            POWER(SIN((RADIANS(-77.399994 - `locations`.`gps_lng` ) ) / 2 ), 2 )
          ),
          SQRT(1-(
            POWER(SIN((RADIANS(37.367485 - `locations`.`gps_lat` ) ) / 2 ), 2 ) +
            COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`gps_lat`)) *
            COS(RADIANS(37.367485)) *
            POWER(SIN((RADIANS(-77.399994 - `locations`.`gps_lng` ) ) / 2 ), 2 )
          ))
        )
      ))
AS 'distance'
FROM  `locations` 
JOIN  `companies` ON  `locations`.`co_id` 
HAVING  distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

---

For those curious on my application, Final PHP:

GET Value: `?lat=37.367485&lng=-77.399994`

```php
$earth_radius_miles = 3959; // Earth radius in miles
$earth_radius_kilometers = 6371; // Earth radius in kilometers
$result_radius = 10000; // Maximum distance in either miles or kilometers

$get_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$get_lng = $_GET["lng"];

$dbSelect = mysql_query("SELECT  `companies`.`customerName`,
(2 * (".$earth_radius_miles." * ATAN2(
          SQRT(
            POWER(SIN((RADIANS(".$get_lat." - `locations`.`gps_lat` ) ) / 2 ), 2 ) +
            COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`gps_lat`)) *
            COS(RADIANS(".$get_lat.")) *
            POWER(SIN((RADIANS(".$get_lng." - `locations`.`gps_lng` ) ) / 2 ), 2 )
          ),
          SQRT(1-(
            POWER(SIN((RADIANS(".$get_lat." - `locations`.`gps_lat` ) ) / 2 ), 2 ) +
            COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`gps_lat`)) *
            COS(RADIANS(".$get_lat.")) *
            POWER(SIN((RADIANS(".$get_lng." - `locations`.`gps_lng` ) ) / 2 ), 2 )
          ))
        )
      ))
AS 'distance'
FROM  `locations` 
JOIN  `companies` ON  `locations`.`co_id` 
HAVING  distance < ".$result_radius."
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 10") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

**Results:**

```
[{"customerName":"SOME COMPANY","distance":"0"}]
```

I have tested these results with other coordinates and seems to be working perfectly. Haven't tested anything with great distance between the two points but my application doesn't require me to do so.

Comment: Can't validate, but +1 for presentation

Answer (score 1):

Ashok, you can calculate the distance between two cordinates by using the below formula:

[image]

where

```
R  =  radius of the earth (6,371 km)
Δlat =  |lat2- lat1|
Δlong = |long2- long1|
```